# The driver has not received any packets from the server in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Im trying to connect my intelliJ java project with mysql for the first time and unfortunately I get this error :

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
at sundos.ConnectionConfig.getConnect(ConnectionConfig.java:15)
at sundos.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: 
Communications link failure
```

I already added the mysql-connector.
here is a simple code of me :

```
public static Connection getConnect (){

    Connection connection = null;

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" , "root" , "12345");
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return connection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem in my project. I solved It by changing localhost with server ip in connection url

```
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.3.3:3306/test" , "root" , "12345");
```

Also make sure that your mysql server is running and your username and password are correct.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your `Mysql server` is up and running:

#### steps:

1. check if `MySQL80` service is running
2. try connect to your database using  `mysqlWorkbench` or any other tool
3. rerun your app

Note: for windows you can access `MySQL80` service by searching for `services`